# MongoDB 3.2 - Admin user not authorized to execute command

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have created an admin level user and given the dbAdminAnyDatabase, userAdminAnyDatabase, readWriteAnyDatabase permissions on the admin database as well as my other database and I can create a successful connection to the client but when I try to run a command to retreive data I get an error saying 'Command find failed: not authorized on {database} to execute command'.

Any ideas on why this isn't working?

Comment: need more info and details. but I guess when you mongo to the database, you need to add --authenticationDatabase option, such as mongo -u foo --authenticationDatabase admin -p ......

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found an example where the user was made to have "root" access and now I can successfully query data.  The question still remains why the above credentials didn't work.

Comment: Can you give more info about the failed username? By running use yourdatabase and 
db.getUser("your user")

Comment: @BAE The username isn't the issue.  It successfully authorizes and connects to the database but when I try to run a read command it fails with the above error.  The username has the above permissions on the admin database as well as the database I am trying to query